# API call me/posts throwing OAuthException - #1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

Not sure if anything changed today (April 3rd 2013), but started getting OAuthException #1 when trying to retrieve user posts (me/posts). I have properly authenticated/authorized token with permissions including read_stream. The app has been working all along for the last few months, but started failing starting this morning. me/likes and other calls seem to be working fine. Any idea what could be wrong?

I'm using Facebook C# SDK - tried with the latest version of the code from Github, to no avail.

Comment: Have you ever thought about reading exception message? Do you always prefer to guess instead of reading?

Answer (score 1):

As, zerkms said, clearly your token seems to be expired. Facebook long term token expires after 60 days and you need to get it again. You can read more on Facebook developer website [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) . Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry...but am using new access tokens for every access and still get the error...I get the same error going through Graph API Explorer as well...In Graph API Explorer tried "Get Access Token" followed by Get "me/posts" and I get  "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1"

Comment: Can you please show more details about the query that you are making?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts
as mentioned, I do Get Access Token followed by Submit.
Get Access Token has Extended Permissions with read_stream checked.

Comment: Try to run following query with read_access permissions in graph explorer:
/me/?fields=posts.fields(id,message)

It shows the results for me. Whatever you want from the feed just specify in brackets.

Comment: me?fields=posts.fields(id,message) seem to be returning id and create_time of posts, no message field. Do you get results when you try me/posts? Thanks for your time.

Comment: sorry, message field is there for some posts, but did you try paging - clicking on the next or prev link in the graph api explorer? Do you get results when you try to page using the me?fields-posts.fields(id,message)? I get the same auth exception when I try to click on the paging links.

Comment: Thats what I said in the previous message. It depends on what details of the posts so you want? You can get id, message, type of post, name that is shown, the description.. everything about the post if you try to add the details with in the bracket. Those posts for which nothing is available, you won't get the corresponding info. 
Try following to get the more details: 
me/?fields=posts.fields(id,message,source,name,status_type,link,description)

Also, I don't understand what do mean 'paging links' and 'try to page'?

Comment: Thanks again...in Graph API explorer, once you submit the query with fields=posts.fields(id,message), scroll down to the bottom of the results and you should see a paging section with previous and next links to retrieve the previous/next set of posts (assuming you have enough # of posts) 

Do you get any results when you click on posts on this page? [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)